# Enabling Weblogic for remote JMX access now makes it unable to connect locally

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jmx, visualvm

I have an app deployed to my local WebLogic instance (10.3.6) on my Win7 laptop.  It's creating Beans through Spring and registering them in the local MBeanServer.  I can open up VisualVM, see the "WebLogic" process and see the mbeans that I've registered.  This works fine.

I then wanted to set up my JVM for remote JMX access.  I took the simple-minded approach for now and set the following properties:

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8888 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true

I made sure the "jmxremote.access" and "jmxremote.password" file in my JRE was set appropriately.

I started it up, then opened up VisualVM on my Linux box and created a remote host entry for the IP address of my laptop, then a JMX connect to port 8888, and specified the name:pwd pair I set in the jmxremote.access and jmxremote.password files.  This all worked fine.  I could see all the same registered mbeans.

Then, I went back to my laptop and looked my local VisualVM, and I saw that there was no "WebLogic" process.  It appears that enabling my JVM for remote JMX access has disabled local access.  Is this supposed to happen?  Is there a way to configure this?  This isn't necessarily a big problem, I just need to understand it.

Comment: Does WebLogic run under the same user as VisualVM? This would be the easiest explanation, why you don't see it in VisualVM, since VisualVM sees java applications running under the same user as VisualVM itself.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood what I wrote.  Without the "jmx" command-line arguments, I can see the WebLogic process in VisualVM.  When I provide those arguments, I cannot see it.  In any case, I'm running VisualVM as the same user that's running WebLogic.